# Share button not working in my app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, whatsapp

I have created a **simple website app** using **webview** in **android studio** and given it **internet access permission** also **enabled java script** on app

When I have added a WhatsApp share button using this code

```
 <button>
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=HERE GOES THE URL ENCODED TEXT YOU WANT TO SHARE" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
</button>
```

This is working well in all mobile browsers but when I try to use this on my app I am getting an error screen saying

> Web page not available
>
> The web page
>   at whatsapp://send?text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20salecould
>   not be loaded because:
>
> net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

This is my code in mainactivity.java

```
package com.a4extras.ukzz.whatsappdaily;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mywebView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebView.loadUrl("http://ukzz4u.blogspot.com/2017/11/whatsapp-share-01.html");
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }}
```

This is because my app is taking whatsapp:// as a URL 
So how can prevent this so that the Share button will work properly

Please help me with necessary script
Thanks

Comment: On a device, this should work as it is. Are you trying it on a simulator? Do you have WhatsApp installed on the device?

Comment: Your URL should be simply **whatsapp://send?text=HERE GOES THE URL ENCODED TEXT YOU WANT TO SHARE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple workaround is to use *javascript* in `href`:

```
<a href="javascript:go('whatsapp://send?text=HERE')">Share</a>
```

or, if using Chrome based webview:

```
<a href="intent://send?text=HERE#Intent;scheme=whatsapp;package=com.whatsapp;end">Share</a>
```

More complex, but more powerful solution is to control whatsapp scheme by yourself:

In your WebViewClient:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    Uri uri = request.getUrl();
    if (Objects.equals(uri.getScheme(), "whatsapp")) {
        try {
            Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(request.getUrl().toString(), Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
            if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
                startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
}
```

Comment: OK, in `WebViewClient` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method you can override default action. I will modify an answer.

Comment: Is it Uri or URL

Comment: I have included my app script please help me your code is not working

Comment: Instead of setting default `new WebViewClient()` it's required to override it: `mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { @override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading { code from an answer } });`